# "Save 38% now" C string aborts the program

Tags: c, objective-c, char, freebsd, stdio

## TL;DR

The C string `"% n"`, **with a space** between `'%'` and `'n'` characters (like in "Save 38% now" string) is treated as `"%n"`, which is considered a vulnerability since latest OS releases, and it leads to abort the program.

(please see UPD 1 and UPD 2)

## Background

I am investigating an issue with the logging in my app. The app receives some string from the server, which we log with function similar to `NSLog`. The format we call that function is:

```
MyLog(@"%@", message);
```

In one case, message contains text "Save 38% now". At this point the app crashes.

## Issue

While looking into it I was able to pinpoint the issue. The full code is below.

```
#define FOO(FORMAT, ...) (\
{\
char *str;\
str = [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##VA_ARGS] UTF8String];\
str;\
}\
)\

#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        char *foo = FOO(@"%@", @"Save 38% now");
        printf(foo);
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Instantiate class anywhere,

```
MyClass *my = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

, and the app will crash upon `printf(foo);` with the message:

```
%n used in a non-immutable format string
```

Basically, the string "% n", with a space between "%" and "n" is threated as "%n", which is considered a vulnerability since latest OS releases.

## Discussion

I am still trying to proof my thoughts and find a way to solve the issue...

1. I believe, the code responsible for the crash is this: https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1244.30.3/stdio/FreeBSD/vfprintf.c Am I risgt?
2. Why the space between two characters does not make any difference for the code?
3. How could I possibly work around it leaving the same approach?

...so far, it looks like a bug.

## Solution

Based on answers given by the community, right now my *workaround* to the issue is this (see also "UPD" part where I added the actual code where the issue originally occurred):

```
message = [plainText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%"
withString:@"%%" 
options:NSRegularExpressionSearch 
range:NSMakeRange(0, message.length)];

DebugOnlyLog(@"%@", message);
```

## UPD 1

This is the code I use to log some

```
#import <os/log.h>

extern struct os_log_s _os_log_default;
extern __attribute__((weak)) void _os_log_internal(void *dso, os_log_t log, os_log_type_t type, const char *message, ...);

#define DebugOnlyLog(FORMAT, ...) \
void(*ptr_os_log_internal)(void *, __strong os_log_t, os_log_type_t type, const char *, ...) = _os_log_internal;\
if (ptr_os_log_internal != NULL) {\
_os_log_internal(&__dso_handle, OS_OBJECT_GLOBAL_OBJECT(os_log_t, _os_log_default), 0x00, [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);\
}
```

## UPD 2

After the community response, it has become clear that there are two issues here:

1. There is a problem with the approach of passing format string into `print()` function.
2. There is a problem in using private API (`_os_log_internal(...)`) instead of `os_log` in similar fashion (see the "UPD 1" section, where I provided the code being used).

---

Note: I also posted [the same question to Apple Developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661837).

Comment: `printf(foo);` - that's the biggest problem. *Never* do that. `printf("%s", foo)` . If a newline is desired afterward, then `puts(foo)`. Either way, don't be sending arbitrary strings as universal messages to `printf`

Comment: the `printf(foo);` here is just an example. it happens with other API too.

Comment: I assume the other APIs also require static strings, right?

Comment: Then include the other APIs, because thus far this isn't a runtime library vulnerability as much as it is bad programming practices.

Comment: @WhozCraig I posed the snipped I use for Debug logging where this issue occurs. Thanks.

Comment: "considered a vulnerability since latest OS releases" is not accurate. Rather, your program just has undefined behavior by using a `%n` specifier with no corresponding argument, and the underlying reason is that you're trying to pass a literal string where a format string (that needs the `%` quoted) is needed.

Comment: `puts(foo)` is safe and also puts newline at the end.  And it's shorter to type. What's not to like? (Or use `fputs(out, stdout)` if you really don't want the neeline.)

Comment: I've rooted servers by exploiting this bug... 20 years ago, so this is not exactly new...

Comment: In your os_log wrapper, you seem to be trying to bypass the existing `os_log` define. First, you should use that rather than reaching into undocumented internals. The problem (which os_log likely would have made clearer at compile time) is that you cannot pass a non-static string to os_log in this field. os_log does very tricky and non-obvious interpolation on the string it's passed. It does this for both performance and security reasons. Rewrite this around os_log directly, and see the WWDC video explaining os_log. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721/

Comment: @RobNapier thank you very much for the help. It would be great to see your last point about os_log as a part of your answer, if you'd have time to move it here. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: Agreed, and moved. Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is simply wrong, and the system is telling you so, and exactly why:

```
printf(foo);
```

This is a classic security problem. The correct code is:

```
printf("%s", foo);
```

`foo` is not a static string, and it is a security mistake to pass `foo` to a function that performs %-substitutions.

The reason a space doesn't matter is because the space is part of the format string. `% n` is a format specifier that includes space padding (even though that doesn't make sense for the `n` type, it's still legal). See the [printf man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for a full description of the % specifiers. They're quite complicated and powerful, which is exactly why they're so dangerous, and you can't hand uncontrolled strings to them.

There's a quick description of the security problem at Wikipedia's [Uncontrolled format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string).

---

In your os_log wrapper, you seem to be trying to bypass the existing os_log define. First, you should use that rather than reaching into undocumented internals. The problem (which os_log likely would have made clearer at compile time) is that you cannot pass a non-static string to os_log in this field. os_log does very tricky and non-obvious interpolation on the string it's passed. It does this for both performance and security reasons. Rewrite this around os_log directly, and see the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/721) explaining os_log.

Answer (score 1):

You need use `puts` instead of `printf`, because `printf` expects first argument to be string format.
`puts` just puts plain string into output.